# Magento 1: adminhtml controller rewrite and module dependencies

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, overrides, controllers, admin-controller

### Explanation

So I have a module, I'll call it `Hello_World` with the following code in `config.xml`

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Hello_World before="Mage_Adminhtml">Hello_World_Adminhtml</Hello_World>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Under the `controllers/Adminhtml` folder **I have two controllers which DO NOT EXTEND any core Magento controllers.**

On the other hand, I have another module called `Bye_World` with the same code in `config.xml`:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Bye_World before="Mage_Adminhtml">Bye_World_Adminhtml</Bye_World>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Under the `controllers/Adminhtml` folder **I have one controller which DOES EXTEND a core Magento controller**

### Problem

If I try to **make `Bye_World` depending on `Hello_World`** by adding the following to my `app/etc/modules/Bye_World.xml` :

```
<depends>
    <Hello_World />
</depends>
```

Then **my `Bye_World` adminhtml controller core rewrite won't be called anymore even though there's no `Hello_World` adminhtml controller that rewrites the same core controller.**

So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What if you add `before="Hello_World"` in your xml?

Comment: @DavidManners hmmm that did it. Feel free to post that as an answer however I'm not sure why I need to do that as there's no controller conflicts between both modules ? That kinda confuses me

Answer (score 5):

So as far as I understand it you will need to update your module's config xml to also include the adminhtml dependency. To do this you should include the following in your `Bye_World` config.

```
before="Hello_World"
```

The reason for this is....

Comment: That sounds like a good reason xD

Comment: hahaha @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I was looking into this and then got distracted by a customer.